# Render back a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, render, partial

I have a page composed of several partial in RoR.
The partial will appear as the user press some button, and they're rendered in the same page.
When I change the page, I want that the back button of the browser redirect me not in the index page without the partial rendered, but exactly in the same page already composed by the several partial as it was before I left.

Is it possible ?
If yes how ?

Comment: You can do this with hashbang URLs.

Comment: What does it mean ? Can you be more specific ?

Comment: I read that the hashbang url is an "horrible" practice isn't it ?

Comment: That is an opinion with some merit for the perspectives that it advances. However that hasn't really stopped Github, Facebook, Kotaku and a couple of others from implementing it in a few areas.

The way to do this is fairly well documented on the web. If you're having trouble with the code, ask a question! :)

Answer (score 1):

You might consider setting a session variable, or a cookie, that stores a bit of information about the current user's browsing.

In my app I have a couple of toggles that open expanded toolbars, and if the user has opened it I want it to stay open for them whether they reload or go back etc.

So, do to this, I have an AJAX request when they click the button (which it looks like you're going to do already in order to render partials on a click).

In the controller action to show the partial I would include something like:

```
...
session[:user_options][:partial_name] = true
...
```

Then in your view you can say:

```
- if session[:user_options][:partial_name] = true
  = render 'partial'
```

The only *gotcha* is you'll have to ensure that session[:user_options] is defined throughout your app, or else you'll sometimes get nil object errors.

I don't know if this is really the *best* solution for your particular problem, but it is *a* solution that I'm familiar with. Test it out a bit, maybe you can remix the basic idea to fit what you need.